# Formatting a number extracted from regex

Tags: regex, powershell, filesize

I've tried multiple methods to format a number and convert it to KB but it's just not working and can use some help on the correct format/method to perform this action

```
((robocopy $Root NULL $Filter $params)) | ForEach {
            If ($_ -match "(?<Size>\d+)\s(?<Date>\S+\s\S+)\s+(?<FullName>.*)")
            {
                $Report += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    Size = "{0:N1}" -f $matches.Size / 1KB
                    #Size = [System.Math]::Round(([long]$matches.Size / 1KB), 2)
                    Date = [datetime]$matches.Date
                    FullName = $matches.FullName
                }
            }
```

either method returns the size in bytes without any conversion of the filesize.

Answer (score 2):

`-f` takes precedence over `/`, so you end up with the result of:

```
("{0:N1}" -f $matches.Size) / 1KB
```

Nest the second operation in parentheses and it'll work:

```
Size = "{0:N1}" -f ($matches.Size / 1KB)
```

Comment: Thank for the input @Mathias R. Jessen.  I actually found the problem and a bit embarrassed admitting that I have the same line of code in another location which it was hitting based on the condition.  Guess I need to start building some functions call so I don't do that again.

Comment: Relevant help topic: [about_Operator_Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence)